# sql query not executed

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to this query executed,But it print  @TABLESQL11 value but not executed.Can any one help to execute.

```
declare @maxCount int

set @maxCount=3

DECLARE @TABLESQL11 VARCHAR(4000)

set @TABLESQL11='insert into temp11 '

set @TABLESQL11=@TABLESQL11+ 'select attendeeid,Activities,date,time'

DECLARE @j INT

SET @j =1

WHILE @j <=@maxCount

BEGIN

    set @TABLESQL11 = @TABLESQL11+',q'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j)+',A'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,@j)

        SET @j = @j+1

END
set @TABLESQL11=@TABLESQL11+' from temp1'

print @TABLESQL11

exec (@TABLESQL11)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run all but the Exec you get the following (formatted in [Instant SQL Formatter](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm) )

```
INSERT INTO temp11 
SELECT attendeeid, 
       activities, 
       DATE, 
       TIME, 
       q1, 
       a1, 
       q2, 
       a2, 
       q3, 
       a3 
FROM   temp1
```

There's nothing in the statement by itself to indicate that there's a SQL Syntax issue. This leads one to conclude that the problem is one of the following.

1. There's no data in temp1
2. You're getting an error that you forgot to mention (like there's a mismatch between the # of fields in temp11 and the select statement )
3. The data is being inserted into temp11 but for some reason you're not seeing it

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand of the code provided, make sure that the proper columns exist in both table temp1 AND temp11. q1, A1, etc.

When executing, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

**set @TABLESQL11=@TABLESQL11+' '+'select attendeeid,Activities,date,time'**